# Three JS Drag Controls Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, vuetify.js

So I am trying to drag the spheres around the scene. The dragcontrols are supposed to be activated whenever the "m" key is pressed. The current problem is that whenever I am trying to drag an object, it doesn't move and I get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined at HTMLCanvasElement.onDocumentMouseMove". Do you guys have any idea why it is happening? (I tried to omit as much unnecessary for the problem code as possible. Sorry if it looks messy)

```
<template>
  <div class="flex fill-height wrap">
    <div id="map"  class="flex fill-height wrap "  v-on:dblclick="addNewPoi3d" ></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import  DragControls from 'drag-controls';

var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);

var PLYLoader = require('three-ply-loader');

PLYLoader(THREE);

export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  data() {
    return {
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      camera: null,
      controls: null,
      mouse: new THREE.Vector2(),
      canvasPosition: null,
      rayCaster: new THREE.Raycaster(),
      spheres: [],
      objects: [],
      moveIt: false,
      plymap: null,
      mapWidth: null,
      mapHeight: null,
      mapDimensions: null,
      intersectsScene: null,
      intersectsPoi:null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.mapId = this.$route.params.mapId;
    this.fetchMapData(this.mapId);
    this.plymap = this.MapStore.ply;
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      let map = document.getElementById('map');
      this.mapDimensions = map.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.mapWidth = this.mapDimensions.width;
      this.mapHeight = this.mapDimensions.height;
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        60,
        this.mapWidth/this.mapHeight,
        0.1,
        1000,
      );
      this.camera.position.z = 3;

      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      this.renderer.setSize(this.mapWidth, this.mapHeight);
      map.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


      // EVENT LISTENERS:
      map.addEventListener('mousedown', this.movePoi, false);
      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onDocumentKeyDown, false);
      document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onDocumentKeyUp, false);

    },

    // FUNCTIONS:
    onDocumentKeyDown(event) {

      let keycode = event.which;
      if (keycode === 77) {
        this.moveIt = true;
        this.controls.enabled = false;
      }
    },
    onDocumentKeyUp(event){
      let keycode = event.which;
      if (keycode === 77) {
        this.moveIt = false;
        this.controls.enabled = true;
      }
    },
    mouseOverScene (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

      this.mouse.x = ( x / this.mapWidth) * 2 - 1;
      this.mouse.y = - ( y / this.mapHeight ) * 2 + 1;

      this.rayCaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
    },

    //POI placement:

    addNewPoi3d(event) {
      if (event) {
        this.mouseOverScene(event);
      };
      event.preventDefault();

      let sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.1, 32, 32);
      let sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff0 } );
      let sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
      sphere.name = 'spherePOI';

      let intersects = this.intersectsScene;
      intersects = this.rayCaster.intersectObject(this.scene.getObjectByName('floor'));

      sphere.position.set(
        intersects[0].point.x,
        intersects[0].point.y + sphereGeometry.parameters.radius,
        intersects[0].point.z
      );

      this.spheres.push(this.scene.getObjectByName('spherePOI'));
      this.objects.push(sphere);
      this.scene.add( sphere );


    },

    //POI movement around the scene:
    movePoi (event) {
      if (this.moveIt) {
        this.mouseOverScene(event);
        event.preventDefault();

      let intersectsPoi = this.intersectsPoi;
      intersectsPoi = this.rayCaster.intersectObject(this.scene.getObjectByName('spherePOI'));
      console.log(intersectsPoi[0].object);
      console.log(intersectsPoi[0].object.name);

      if (intersectsPoi.length > 0 && intersectsPoi[0].object.name === 'spherePOI') {
        let controlsDrag = new DragControls(this.objects, this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
      };
      };
    },



    animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
      this.render();
    },
    render() {
      this.controls.update();
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.init();
    this.animate();
  },
};
</script>
```

EXPECTED: The objects should be draggable.

ACTUAL: Well, they are not :D I get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined at HTMLCanvasElement.onDocumentMouseMove".

Comment: it seems like it doesn't define the _mouse in the THREE.DragControls module... I wonder how can that be done though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved! All I needed to do is add `DragControls.install({THREE: THREE})` to the init() phase.