# click event in mesh for threejs

Tags: three.js

I used below code to **add click event** in **mesh** for **three js**.

```html
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var targetMesh
function onMouseClick( event ) {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var isIntersected = raycaster.intersectObject( targetMesh );
    if (isIntersected) {
        console.log('Mesh clicked!')
    }
}
function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
window.addEventListener( 'mouseclick', onMouseClick, false );
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
```

but getting an error as

> ERROR Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'x') in threejs

i got a solution from below link
[Three JS Drag Controls Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306622/three-js-drag-controls-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-x-of-undefined)

But i **dont want DragControls** i **need only click event for mesh**.please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mouse.set(x, y)` instead. `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` are getters not setters.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector2

Comment: but still mouse event is working for mesh

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: can u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378725/click-event-issue-in-mesh-for-threejs in that i have added my code for reference

Comment: can u please me to fix the issue for the click event in mesh.