# click event issue in mesh for threejs

Tags: three.js

I used below code to add **click even**t in mesh for **three js.**

```html
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var targetMesh
function onMouseClick( event ) {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var isIntersected = raycaster.intersectObject( targetMesh );
    if (isIntersected) {
        console.log('Mesh clicked!')
    }
}
function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
window.addEventListener( 'mouseclick', onMouseClick, false );
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
```

> ERROR
> ERROR
> Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setFromCamera')
> please help to clear the issue i have **attached my code also**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-threejs-demo-basic-umcvaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: tried with another method:
     var domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
      domEvents.addEventListener(plane1, 'click', function(event){
        console.log('you clicked on the mesh')
      }, false)

Comment: here also showing error Cannot find name 'THREEx'. Even after added threex doc.js script

Comment: Should be "THREE" not "THREEx". Good luck!

Comment: i tried that but not working

Comment: when i change to THREE then DomEvents will not work

Comment: Can you please add the error as it is printed in the dev console (F12)? What you shared does not look like a standard error.